# Is converting floating point number to integer defined behavior

Tags: c++, floating-point, undefined-behavior

today have found that VS2010 do not support `round` function in C++ projects. Info about that function have found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/). Also noticed that there also no `trunc` function.

So have tried some stuff and noticed some behavior that may help in such situation.

---

```
float a = 2.999;
int b = (int)a;   //gives 2
```

---

```
float a = -2.999;
int b = (int)a;   //gives -2
```

---

This works as truncation so I could use that, however I don't want to use code which leads to undefined behavior. So would like to ask if this is defined or undefined behavior.

**EDIT:** I'm not asking about C++11 as I'm using VS2008.

Comment: 4.9 is *almost* unchanged from C++98 to C++11, it just uses "prvalue" instead of "rvalue" which does not make any difference. My answer applies to C++98 as well as C++11.

Answer (score 5):

It is clearly defined in

> #### 4.9 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]
>
> <sup>1</sup> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion trun- cates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type. [ *Note:* If the destination type is `bool`, see 4.12. — *end note* ]

Answer (score 2):

It's not undefined behavior.

> #### C++11 §4.9 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]
>
> An rvalue of a floating point type can be converted to an rvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type. [ Note: If the destination type is bool, see 4.12. —end note ]

Comment: I'm using VS2008 and it doesn't support C++11.

Comment: @ST3 I'm sure it's the same in C++03.

Comment: @ST3 it is the same in C++03, also in **4.9**.